# IDE Support for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, ide

Hey guys I'm a newbie and I just wanted to know of the people who do Winforms on Visual studio, at your place of work do your forms have IDE support. Because for some reason I don't have IDE support on 99% of the windows forms I'm working with. I mean I can not see anything on the design view except for errors is this the usual case in industry????

Comment: No.  Errors are not the usual case in the industry.  The standard is at least for the IDE to not give any errors when opening, viewing, modifying, saving, compiling or testing your project.

Comment: Thanks Mike so you are telling me that I should be able to see the form in design view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, WinForms is not broken for us (me). Check your code. Sometimes WinForms applications that were developed under Visual Sudio 2003 (or earlier) when upgraded to Visual Studio 2005 (or later) become unstable.

Start with a new form, and if the IDE (it is called a visual designer) works fine, then think about re-creating the old forms from scratch with the newest VS installation.

Comment: Is having visual designer support very important?

Comment: You are designing a user-interface based desktop application so obviously the designer support would be important, in that you can view and edit the layout of the various UI elements, their positions, alignment, sizing and all such factors.

Comment: Make sure you haven't deleted any of the auto-generated files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any 3rd party UI controls? Some have dll's for the design view to work, and if you haven't installed the toolkit on your developer machine you might get errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation for having errors on forms is licensing. If your company uses third-party controls on their forms, they could cause errors when trying to display the forms on unlicensed machines.

Another possible explanation for errors with third-party controls is simply installation. If you don't have the controls installed and referenced properly, that could also cause errors.

You could try to post some of the errors you have to another Stack Overflow question, and perhaps the community could help you solve your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear!, if the Visual Studio Designer not working well then re-install the IDE

Or explain more...

Comment: Sorry Rami, I meant that I can not see any of the forms in design view is that usual in industry for windows applications?

Comment: @Darth: No that is not usual, you must see the design otherwise how could you design it in first place, you got an issue with your VS designer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the forms in the design view. 
Always unless there is an error in code. In case the project is building you should get the same error (this is a runtime error) that you will generally get when you run the code. 

 In case the project is not building it will be simpler to fix the errors :)